# Sharepoint Javascript Lists

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, survey, usergroups

Is it possible to iterate through a survey response list using javascript on a webform in Sharepoint?

Is it also possible to iterate through a user group list as well - again using javascript?

Additionally, is it possible to create a table or list or something to:
a) Display a group of users
b) Display their responses to a survey

using javascript?

Answer (score 1):

**Iterating through a web form**

Yes certainly this is possible. You can search Stack Overflow for [questions tagged jQuery+SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint+jquery) or [JavaScript+SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint+javascript) for examples to this. Also see [End User SharePoint](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/) and their jQuery articles for more examples.

**Create a table or list to display users and their survey responses using JavaScript**

This is out of the box functionality with a SharePoint survey list without needing to use JavaScript. However if you really need to retrieve the data using JavaScript, there is the web service option described in the article [Calling the SharePoint Web Services with jQuery](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2009/04/09/calling-the-sharepoint-web-services-with-jquery.aspx), and the RPC option described in the article [JQuery for Everyone: Get XML List Data with OWSSVR.DLL (RPC)](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/?p=1533).

**Iterate through a user group list using JavaScript**

Again, this should be possible using either of the two options from the previous section.